# Android's browser compatibility

Tags: android, html, css, layout, cross-browser

I have just finished my first website and I uploaded it to Github to test it with a couple different devices. I used html5, css3, a little bit of Javascript and a little bit of jQuery and **I tried to make it 100% responsive.**

So I checked with a smaller Desktop and the website was just as I intended it to be. I checked with an iPhone 4s and it was perfect, and the same thing happened with the iPhone 6s. However, when I tried it with my **Samsung S3 mobile phone** I saw that a couple sections of my website were **not as I intended**.

The main problem was with all linear-gradient's. For example:

- `background:linear-gradient(to right, #f2f2f2, #f7cf9f);`

So instead of being gradient it shows no color at all ("transparent" I'm guessing...). And to clarify, **this only happened on the android's default browser**, if I opened the website with the Samsung S3 but using chrome everything was as intended.

**So could anyone help me by telling me how I could fix this? Thank you very much in advance!**

Comment: CSS gradient should be supported by all Android Browsers, but the old ones require `-webkit-`. For more info what's supported have a look here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Comment: I see that the version 4.3 is too old and needs the -webkit-. However, is this true for even older versions? I saw that my S3 is a 4.2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used for my homepage :

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, color-stop(0, #3f95ea), color-stop(1, #0066FF));
background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(top left, #3f95ea 0%, #0066FF 100%);
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3f95ea 0%, #0066FF 100%);
background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(top left, #3f95ea 0%, #0066FF 100%);
```